# SQL - Rows that are repetitive with a particular condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table like this:

```
 +----+-------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
| ID |  Name | RecievedService | FirstZoneTeeth | SecondZoneTeeth | ThirdZoneTeeth | FourthZoneTeeth |
+----+-------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  1 |  John |   SomeService1  |       13       |                 |        4       |                 |
+----+-------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  2 |  John |   SomeService1  |       34       |                 |                |                 |
+----+-------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  3 | Steve |   SomeService3  |                |                 |                |        2        |
+----+-------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  4 | Steve |   SomeService4  |                |                 |                |        12       |
+----+-------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Every digit in zones is a tooth (dental science) and it means "John" has got "SomeService1" twice for tooth #3.

```
+----+------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
| ID | Name | RecievedService | FirstZoneTeeth | SecondZoneTeeth | ThirdZoneTeeth | FourthZoneTeeth |
+----+------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  1 | John |   SomeService1  |       13       |                 |        4       |                 |
+----+------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  2 | John |   SomeService1  |       34       |                 |                |                 |
+----+------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Note that Steve has received services twice for tooth #2 (4th Zone) but services are not one.

I'd write some code that gives me a table with duplicate rows (Checking the only patient and received service)(using "group by" clause") but I need to check zones too.

I've tried this:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by vv.ID_sick) as RowNum,
        bb.Radif,
        bb.VCount as 'Count',
        vv.ID_sick 'ID_Sick', 
        vv.ID_service 'ID_Service',
        sick.FNamesick + ' ' + sick.LNamesick as 'Sick',
        serv.NameService as 'Service',
        vv.Mab_Service as 'MabService',
        vv.Mab_daryafti as 'MabDaryafti',
        vv.datevisit as 'DateVisit',
        vv.Zone1,
        vv.Zone2,
        vv.Zone3,
        vv.Zone4,
        vv.ID_dentist as 'ID_Dentist',
        dent.FNamedentist + ' ' + dent.LNamedentist as 'Dentist',
        vv.id_do as 'ID_Do',
        do.FNamedentist + ' ' + do.LNamedentist as 'Do'
     from visiting vv inner join (
            select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.ID_sick ASC) AS Radif,
            count(a.ID_sick) as VCount,
             a.ID_sick,
              a.ID_service 
             from visiting a 
        group by a.ID_sick, a.ID_service, a.Zone1, a.Zone2, a.Zone3, a.Zone4
        having count(a.ID_sick)>1)bb 
        on vv.ID_sick = bb.ID_sick and vv.ID_service = bb.ID_service 
        left join InfoSick sick on vv.ID_sick = sick.IDsick
        left join infoService serv on vv.ID_service = serv.IDService
        left join Infodentist dent on vv.ID_dentist = dent.IDdentist
        left join infodentist do on vv.id_do = do.IDdentist
        order by bb.ID_sick, bb.ID_service,vv.datevisit
```

But this code only returns rows with all tooths repeated. What I want is even one tooth repeats ...

How can I implement it?

I need to check characters in zones.

**Zone's datatype is varchar

Comment: can you add your ddl and insert script. also could u pls share what you have tried.

Comment: An example of what you would like to get will also be helpful.

Comment: Yes, of course, I'll edit the post and add SQL code

Comment: This is  a bad datamodel for what you are trying to do. Are you allowed to change it?

Comment: No, I'm not allowed to change. The table has an old datamodel

Comment: On a sidenote: The delimiter for names is the double quote in standard SQL and the brackets in SQL Server. The single quote is for string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad datamodel for what you are trying to do. By storing the teeth as a varchar, you have kind of decided that you are not interested in single teeth, but only in the group of teeth. Now, however, you are trying to investigate on single teeth.

You'd want a datamodel like this:

service

```
+------------+--------+-----------------+
| service_id | Name   | RecievedService |
+------------+--------+-----------------+
|  1         |  John  |  SomeService1   |
+------------+--------+-----------------+
|  3         |  Steve |  SomeService3   |
+------------+--------+-----------------+
|  4         |  Steve |  SomeService4   |
+------------+-------+-----------------+
```

service_detail

```
+------------+------+-------+
| service_id | zone | tooth |
+------------+------+-------+
|  1         |  1   |  1    |
|  1         |  1   |  3    |
|  1         |  3   |  4    |
+------------+------+-------+
|  1         |  1   |  3    |
|  1         |  1   |  4    |
+------------+------+-------+
|  3         |  4   |  2    |
+------------+------+-------+
|  4         |  4   |  1    |
|  4         |  4   |  2    |
+------------+------+-------+
```

What you can do with the given datamodel is to create such table on-the-fly using a recursive query and string manipulation:

```
with unpivoted(service_id, name, zone, teeth) as
(
  select recievedservice, name, 1, firstzoneteeth
  from mytable where len(firstzoneteeth) > 0
  union all
  select recievedservice, name, 2, secondzoneteeth
  from mytable where len(secondzoneteeth) > 0
  union all
  select recievedservice, name, 3, thirdzoneteeth
  from mytable where len(thirdzoneteeth) > 0
  union all
  select recievedservice, name, 4, fourthzoneteeth
  from mytable where len(fourthzoneteeth) > 0
)
, service_details(service_id, name, zone, tooth, teeth) as
(
  select
    service_id, name, zone, substring(teeth, 1, 1), substring(teeth, 2, 10000)
  from unpivoted
  union all
  select
    service_id, name, zone, substring(teeth, 1, 1), substring(teeth, 2, 10000)
  from service_details
  where len(teeth) > 0
)
, duplicates(service_id, name) as
(
  select distinct service_id, name
  from service_details
  group by service_id, name, zone, tooth
  having count(*) > 1    
)
select m.*
from mytable m
join duplicates d on d.service_id = m.recievedservice and d.name = m.name;
```

A lot of work and a rather slow query due to a bad datamodel, but still feasable.

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/JVWK49901